# Problem arithmetic $ b=qa+r $ $\Rightarrow$ $a\wedge b=a\wedge r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I want to Prove that:

$ b=qa+r   $$\Rightarrow$$a\wedge b=a\wedge r$

I tried to prove this, but my results doesn't match the correct result

My attempt :

$b=aq+r$$\Rightarrow $$r=b-qa$ $(r≠0)$

Suppose $(*) a\wedge b=k$. $k\in  \mathbb{Z^{*}} $ and $k≠a$

(  note :$a\wedge b$=$gcd(a, b) $)

$a\wedge b=k$$\Rightarrow $ $a=a'k  $ et $b=b'k $

$r=b-qa$$\Rightarrow $$ k(b'-qa') =r$

$\Rightarrow $$ b'-qa'=\frac{r} {k} $

$b'-qa'\in \mathbb{Z} $$\Rightarrow $$ \frac{r} {k} \in \mathbb{Z} $

$\Rightarrow $$r=dk$

$\Rightarrow $$r\wedge k=k(**) $

So after$ (*, **) $ we can see $r\wedge k=a\wedge b $

$(k≠a) $

Where's my mistake?

Comment: Does $\wedge$ denote the greatest common divisor?

Comment: @arthur, yes sir

Answer (score 3):

Let the expresion
$$b=aq+r$$
Suppose $d=gcd(a,b)$ by hypotesis
$d|a$ and $d|b$, notice that $r=b-aq$
and since $d|ax+by$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ in particular for $x=q$ and $y=-1$ we get $d|r$ and $d|a$ then $d$ is a divisor of $r$ and $a$.
Now we prove that $d$ is the maxime, consider $d^{\prime}$ and divisior of $r$ and $a$ we should prove that $d|d^{\prime}$.

Since $d^{\prime}|a$ and $d^{\prime}|r$, notice that $b=aq+r$
and $d^{\prime}|ax+ry$ in particular $d^{\prime}|b$
now  notice tahat
$d^{\prime}|b$ and $d^{\prime}|a$ then $d^{\prime}$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$
by hipotesis since $d$ is the $gcd(a,b)$ then $d|d^{\prime}$
And therfore $d=gcd(a,r)=gcd(a,b)$

Comment: Just, I want to know my mistakes

Comment: Okey. I write the proof and put it

Comment: Nice, but what about my prof?